# OpenFileDialog does not browse the folders under .NET CF

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, openfiledialog

I have an WinMo app and I would like to open a file from the storage card. The file is NOT in the root but within the folder structure. I thought OpenFileDialog would do the trick just as it does under regular .NET. But it does not offer me to navigate over the folders. I looks really lame. Or am I just outstandingly stupid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OFD in the CF, to put it bluntly, sucks.  It has the ability to only browse a few select folders, and as a developer you have no control over what they are.  To browse all folders you need to either [roll your own dialog](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/286) or get [a third-party one](http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx).