# Select Multiple Files in .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: file, compact-framework

The OpenFileDialog does not provide the functionality to select multiple files.
Nor does OpenFileDialogEx (Although better)

How do i get about selecting multiple files in .NET Compact Framework?

Thanx a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own (or use/modify one of [several](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/286) [3rd party](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2008/07/21/c-file-dialog-for-the-compact-framework/) [offerings](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/27460/1954?pf=true)) OpenFileDialog.  Since [the one for the CF sucks anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132163/openfiledialog-does-not-browse-the-folders-under-net-cf), it's probably worth doing.