# access root folder-windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

how to access root folder on windows mobile? I can see only the folder from folder 'my documents'. I use the command -> openfiledialog

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenFileDialog does not browse the folders under .NET CF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132163/openfiledialog-does-not-browse-the-folders-under-net-cf)

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFileDialog in can really only display the Documents and External Storage Card folder. Implementing your own file browser should not be too complicated.

Here's are some articles on the subject:

http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/286

http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/custom-openfiledialog-implementation.html

http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/03/looking-for-openfiledialog-for.html